# Why assigned variable type is number?

Tags: javascript

I have a function look like this.

```
var myfuncsettings;
var myfunc = function(settings) {
    myfuncsettings = settings | {};
    myfuncsettings['prop'] = 'test';
};
```

I got an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on number '0'(…)
```

I consoled.

```
var myfuncsettings;
var myfunc = function(settings) {
    console.log('typeof settings: ' + (typeof settings));
    myfuncsettings = settings | {};
    console.log('typeof myfuncsettings: ' + (typeof myfuncsettings));
    myfuncsettings['message'] = 'test';
};
```

And I got.

```
typeof settings: object
typeof myfuncsettings: number
```

Can anybody please tell me what did I do wrong?

Comment: I understand the down-votes. But this question is not deserve for closing.

Comment: I don't think this counts as a 'typographical error'. A single pipe is perfectly valid, it just does something different than what the OP wants.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. You have explained your issue very well

Comment: @JinKwon I am one of the person who closed. It's just a simple typo. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar: A typo is when you type something you didn't mean to type, the OP intended to use `|` the problem is the OP didn't quite understand what it does is what the problem is. This is not the result of a typo

Comment: @musefan Ah... I guess I can understand the difference. `:)` Thanks.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Don't judge. No it was not a typo. I thought I knew what I was typing. It was a problem, a problem that can be arise on any JavaScript newbies.

Comment: @JinKwon Kindly look at my previous comment. Mistakes happen dude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrong usage of pipeline operator spotted. You have to use it like below for your requirement.

```
myfuncsettings = settings || {};
```

If you use `|`, then it will do a bitwise OR operation between the operands.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I was about to comment that. :) Anyway, lets stick with the rules here.

Answer (score 2):

`|`is a [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR).

> Bitwise operators perform their operations on such binary
>   representations, but **they return standard JavaScript numerical values**.

You're looking for the [logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) `||`

```
myfuncsettings = settings || {};
```

See the Short-circuit evaluation section
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation